# Query for ratio between two queries

Tags: mysql, sql

Say I have a table in a format similar to (but with more items and areas):

```
Item      State     Price
Apple     Georgia   8.00
Apple     Alaska    9.00
Apple     Texas     3.00
Orange    Georgia   5.00
Orange    Alaska    3.00
Orange    Texas     6.00
```

(It's also safe to assume each area has a price for each fruit, and each fruit is listed for each area, so dividing by 0 isn't likely to happen.)

I want to find the ratio of the average price of each fruit in one location to the average price of the fruit in every other location. Doing each individually is simple enough:

(Q1)

```
SELECT AVG(Price) 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE State = 'Georgia' 
GROUP BY Item
```

Finds the average price of each fruit in Georgia, and

(Q2)

```
SELECT AVG(Price) 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE State <> 'Georgia' 
GROUP BY Item
```

Finds the average of each fruit everywhere except for Georgia, but how do I put these two together to get a ratio?

I've tried something like:

```
SELECT Item, Q1/Q2 
FROM TABLE  
GROUP BY Item
```

but I get an error telling me my subquery returns more than one row. Another attempt involves removing the GROUP BY clause in my Q1 and Q2, but then I get is a table with each fruit with the same number in the second column. Any help you could provide would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I'm only interested in the ratio of the price of each item of one particular state over the price of the item over every other state. So, running the query ought to produce a result like:

```
Item      Price(Georgia)/Price(State-[Georgia])
Apple     X
Orange    Y
```

...And so on. What I'm saying is I don't need to find this for every state, just one specific one in particular.

Answer (score 0):

You would do this with subqueries and a `cross join`:

```
select s1.state, s2.state, s1.avgprice / s2.avgprice as stateratio
from (select state, avg(price) as avgprice
      from table t
      group by state
     ) s1 cross join
     (select state, avg(price) as avgprice
      from table t
      group by state
     ) s2
```

Comment: As always, thanks for taking the time to reply, Gordon. I think there might be a disconnect between what we're saying since I'm having some trouble correlating what you're saying to my problem. Your query selects states when I'm looking for items. There should be as many rows as there are items, and one other column has the ratio of the price of that item for a particular (known) state over the price of that item over every other state.

Answer (score 0):

Comparing an item's price in one state with the average price of the item in all states, using a self join:

```
SELECT
  p1.Item, p1.State, p1.price / AVG(p2.price)
FROM
  prices AS p1
  JOIN prices AS p2 ON p1.Item = p2.Item
GROUP BY
  p1.Item,
  p1.State,
  p1.Price
```

Result:

```
ITEM    STATE   P1.PRICE / AVG(P2.PRICE)
Apple   Alaska  1.35
Apple   Georgia 1.2
Apple   Texas   0.45
Orange  Alaska  0.642857
Orange  Georgia 1.071429
Orange  Texas   1.285714
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/32382a/2/0

Note that you can compare an item's price in one state with the average of all *other* states (instead of *all* states) by adding `AND p1.State <> p2.State` to the `JOIN`. That seems less statistically sound, though.

--

OP edit:

> EDIT: I'm only interested in the ratio of the price of each item of
>   one particular state over the price of the item over every other
>   state. So, running the query ought to produce a result like:

Then the query would become:

```
SELECT
  p1.Item, p1.price / AVG(p2.price)
FROM
  prices AS p1
  JOIN prices AS p2 ON p1.Item = p2.Item
WHERE
  p1.State = 'Georgia'
  AND p2.State <> 'Georgia'
GROUP BY
  p1.Item,
  p1.Price
```

Comment: The data wasn't exactly how I needed it to be, but this was a good skeleton that I could (hopefully successfully) meld to the query. I found some really interesting data as a result, too, so thanks a bunch Tomas.

Comment: You're welcome. I've appended my answer after your update and comment. Is this now an answer to your question? As a side remark: I do find it odd to exclude the state you're checking from the average.